# find the optimal model for dataset

Tags: model, statistics, linear-regression, modeling

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDkHw.png)

Hi everyone, i need to find the model to answer the question that young people are going to theater less than before. Could you guy help me to find which model fits the best to this dataset in R?

- Age: numerical value
- Parents_Relevance: ordinal value from 0 to 4. This is the question: "are u agree that the theater is importance in ur home? 0 is agree 100% and 4 is totally not agree
- Persona_Relevance: ordinal value from 0 to 4. This is the question:
  "are u agree that the theater is importance for urself? 0 is agree
  100% and 4 is totally not agree
- Theater_visit_frequency: ordinal value from 0 to 6. 0 is never and 6
  is always visiting theater
- Not_Going_Reason: this counts how many reason in each age

Thanks a lot

I need to find the model with the best fit for this model with R